# a href click() and closure

Tags: jquery

```
var DAYBOOK = {
    22 : 'hmm',
    9 : 'waaaah'
};

function cnstr_submenu(){
    var elm = $('#test');
    for(var key in DAYBOOK){
        (function(key){
            elm.append('<a href="#">'+DAYBOOK[key]+'</a><br>').click(function(){
                alert(key);
            });
        })(key);
    }
};
cnstr_submenu();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9AqVK/

Why is it that all properties in the DAYBOOK object is alerted when you click a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elm.append(...).click` will in fact bind the `click` to the `elm` (the `div`). So when clicking a link, the link doesn't do much - rather the click handlers of the `div` are executed, which has had a function bound for `click` twice.

If you want each link to alert one value, bind the function to the link instead:

```
elm.append( // append the following element
    // create a link with a click handler bound
    $('<a href="#">'+DAYBOOK[key]+'</a><br>').click(function(){
            alert(key);
    })
);
```

Comment: or even better.. $('<a href="#">'+DAYBOOK[key]+'</a>').appendTo(elm)
     .click(function(){
      alert(key);
      
      return false;
     });

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

var DAYBOOK = {
    22 : 'hmm',
    9 : 'waaaah'
};

function cnstr_submenu(){
    var elm = $('#test');
    for(var key in DAYBOOK){
        (function(key){
            elm.append('<a href="#">'+DAYBOOK[key]+'</a>').click(function(){
                alert(key);
            }).append("<br />");
        })(key);
    }
};
cnstr_submenu();
```